# Django and Bootstrap relationship

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a development road map for a django project.  My choosen IDE is pycharm pro and mock up tool is bootstrap studio.  One of my criteria is a calendar and I have discovered that none of the existing public projects will meet my needs so I will have to create one from scratch (no problem). My typical approach would have been that the UI and the django project would be done in near parallel periodically merging and diverging the two.  However, given the ability of the two software tools, I'm starting to think that that a better approach may be to do the UI first in BSS, next import the templates into the django project and finally perform the django dev to meet the needs of the UI.

The specific calendar functionality is not the issue here, this is a methodology question.  While I know that there is a subjective answer to this question (which is not the "answer" I'm looking for here), there also has to be an objective answer as to why this would not work, or be the incorrect approach.

Comment: To be clear, you're asking us to prove a negative here?

Comment: no, but fair question. Given that mock up tools can create the appearance of fully functioning sites I'm asking if it is better to create the UI first then add then import into the framework and do the back end work last.  I already know what the data models need to be and how to call them in the views.  Am I putting the horse before the cart if i do the UI first?  I don't want to run into some nightmare problem due to a known django methodology that I may be missing.

Comment: Unfortunately that's really still a subjective question, and so off-topic here.

Comment: So you are saying that there is not a django recommended approach akin to a pythonic way?   That might be the answer. But if there is a best practice as recommended by django that's not subjective.

Comment: Best practices are subjective, actually. That's what I'm saying.

Comment: __Result:__
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lp1dGmL8qQk

__Tool I Co-wrote to do this:__
https://github.com/enjoysmath/BootstrapStudioToDjango/tree/master

_Please connect with me on the issues forum there if you're interested in getting set up with it._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the UI first is fine if you already know exactly what you want it to do and can specify that.  Doing the Django first lets you play around with a working rough version and get a better feel for what works best before fine tuning the look and feel.  Like you suggest, working on them both together will let each inform the other.